# Array of Struct - Codable

Tags: ios, swift

Please direct me to a possible duplicate, but in my research I wasn't able to figure out a solution.

Here is the JSON Object I'm attempting to decode from my REST API:

```
{
    "name": "Oak",

    "leaves":[
    {
        "id": "1A",
        "damaged": false
    },
    {
        "id": "2A",
        "damaged": false
    },
    {
        "id": "3E",
        "damaged": false
    }
]

}
```

Here is the code so far:

```
struct Tree: Codable {
     var name : String?
     var leaves : [Leaf]?

     init() {
        self.name = string()
        self.leaves = []
     }
 }

struct Leaf: Codable {
     var id : String?
     var damaged : Bool?

     init(){
        self.id = String()
        self.damaged = Bool()
     }
}
```

Now when I consume the API I decode the response using:

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let time = try jsonDecoder.decode(Tree.self, from: data)
```

When I try to decode for this API I get:

"The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

I appreciate any guidance you can provide, thank you!

Also, the init's are there due to their use as a singleton, I'm not looking for a suggestion to not use the singleton pattern, I'm just interested in finding what the problem with this decoding is.

Edit:

Thanks everyone for your responses! I thought the problem was coming from Array of custom Struct, but it was actually much simpler and I feel foolish. Check out my answer below.

So again, thanks everyone for the guidance that humbled myself!

Comment: how you instantiate "data"? can you post the code?

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your code other than `self.name = string()` that should be `self.name = String()`

Comment: I would also recommend declaring your properties as constants. About your Singleton make the property optional

Comment: @soccer343 I tested your code and it worked well... I think your `data` is wrong..

Comment: Please post the full error, not just its `debugDescription`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking at this question for the custom Struct in an array for swift4 this code does work as expected.

I missed a parameter in my data when I asked the question thinking it wasn't the problem. The additional field is now below and my problem was that I was declaring the date as Int32? instead of Int64?.

```
{
    "name": "Oak",
    "discoveryDate": 1514178000000,

    "leaves":[
    {
        "id": "1A",
        "damaged": false
    },
    {
        "id": "2A",
        "damaged": false
    },
    {
        "id": "3E",
        "damaged": false
    }
]

}
```

Which would change the structs to:

```
struct Tree: Codable {
     var name : String?
     var discoveryDate : Int64?
     var leaves : [Leaf]?

     init() {
        self.name = String()
        self.discoveryDate = Int64()
        self.leaves = []
     }
 }

struct Leaf: Codable {
     var id : String?
     var damaged : Bool?

     init(){
        self.id = String()
        self.damaged = Bool()
     }
}
```